# Using regexp_match in PyQGIS script to select features?

Tags: python, pyqgis

I am learning to use Python scripts to automate tasks in my work. I am a beginner in Python and PyQGIS.

I would like to select entities in a layer using regexp_match. It works well in QGIS but I can't transpose it into the Python script.

Could someone tell me how to do it?

Here is my current code:

```
query = "regexp_match(\"COD\" ,'\d.\d\d')"
selshp = shp.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(query))
shp.setSelectedFeatures([f.id() for f in selshp])
```

But no entities are selected while in QGIS I have 670 selected entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this code :

```
query = "regexp_match(\"COD\", '\\\\d.\\\\d\\\\d')"
selshp = shp.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(query))
shp.modifySelection([f.id() for f in selshp], [])
```

- `'\d'` : normal regular expression for digits
- `'\\d'` : this regular expression under QGIS
- `'\\\\d'` : again under Python for escape special characters.

Comment: I made a mistake in the posted code, I wrote it like this '\\d' in the script but I haven't think to write it in Python language with escape char